# USB: Is DATA0 or DATA1 sent in the data stage of a control transaction?

Tags: usb

I'm new to USB a right now quite confused about the DATA0 and DATA1 packets.

In my opinion Cypress explains the USB standard quite well in "[USB 101: An Introduction to Universal Serial Bus 2.0](https://www.cypress.com/file/134171/download)". But in section 9.2.3 where control transactions are explained in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4EBS.png) I'm not sure if that's correct, since when I look on other webpages I see slightly different pictures. Also as I understand it in the USB specification the DATA is toggled after every ACK.
In the data packet of the data stage (marked in the picture with a red border) there is shown a DATA0. But since this DATA are toggled with every ACK, shouldn't there be DATA1?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For Control transfers, the SETUP packet has a Toggle bit of 0 (zero).  If there are any DATA packets to follow, the first one starts with a Toggle bit of 1 (one), each further DATA stage packet toggling this bit.  The STATUS packet always has a Toggle bit of 1 (one), no matter the state of the previous packet.  It is slightly different for BULK transfers.  What is your target platform?  Have you seen my [book](http://www.fysnet.net/the_universal_serial_bus.htm)?

Comment: @fysnet Ok, thank you very much. Now it's clear.